# Flask-Admin MongoEngine column_labels not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

I have following mongoengine model:

```
class User(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=100)
```

and following Flask-Admin ModelView

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    column_labels = {'name': 'MyName', email: 'MyEmail'}
```

This works while list page and detail page but doesn't work for 'create form' and 'edit form'. Which means form field label's text still does not change.

This is a simplified question of my real case problem. I know that we can manipulate this fields in create_form and update_form methods. However, I really don't know what to do when we have EmbeddedDocument and some relations like in the following scenario:

```
class User(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    employee = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Employee)

class Employee(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    job = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    purpose = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    time_for_looking_job = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    education_information = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(EducationInformation))

class EducationInformation(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    education_degree = db.StringField(max_length=100)
    school_name = db.StringField(max_length=100)
```

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: Still open:
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1853

Answer (score 0):

I seen issue like urs with mongoengine, i found partial solution:

```
form_args = dict(
    name=dict(label='MyName')
    email=dict(email='MyEmail')
)
```

Comment: You need to be sure if your solution matches the question. I can see the author has a different question

Comment: Okay. I have same issue, but `form_args` solve my case, just partialy.

Comment: You can use `form_subdocuments` for embedded fields. That's works for me!

Comment: It's not related.